# call an forEachActivty from a body Json of an webActivtity

Tags: sql, json, azure, azure-data-factory

I want to use a pipline ADF to call an API REST  which used an sql table and extracts one or more files.

API should return 3 files if the table contains 3 different regions, for this reason I used the following activities:

A **lokupctivity** : it's a query ( distinct on the column Regions) to get all the regions present in my table.
---------> the result :

```
 "value": [{"RegionCode": "10" },{"RegionCode": "60"},{"RegionCode": "50"}],`
```

**EachActivity**(Check_Region_In_Table) :to call my API for each Region
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jlOf.png)

After that I call my API that use a token, id, secret but in the body i can't get one region
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAQGl.png)

This is my body

`@json(concat('{"sourceTable": "table","query": "select * from table where RegionCode="',activity('Check_Region_In_Table').output.value[0],'","outputFileType" : "csv","optionList":"nullValue=null|delimiter=\t|header=false","outputFolder": "activity('Check_Region_In_Table').output.value[0]",file-{YYYY}-{MM}-{dd}-{HH}-{mm}-{ss}.txt"}'))`
But i get an error that is not valid

The result should return 3 files(i have 3 Regions) with 3 different name R10_file2022-15-04-15-48-30.txt

Comment: If you are inside For Each activity don’t you want to use ‘@item()’ to reference the region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wBob mentioned in comments section, when you are referring lookup output value inside `ForEach` activity, use **item().columnname** {ex: @item().RegionCode}.

- Pass the output of lookup activity in the ForEach activity settings.

[image]

- In your ForEach, use the expression with `item().RegionCode` to refer the lookup column value.

  ```
  @concat('{"sourceTable": "table","query": "select * from table where RegionCode="', item().RegionCode,'","outputFileType" : "csv","optionList":"nullValue=null|delimiter=\t|header=false","outputFolder":', item().RegionCode,'file-{YYYY}-{MM}-{dd}-{HH}-{mm}-{ss}.txt"}')
  ```

Comment: I did what you told , me but i get this error while calling the API : Unexpected Error validating payload

Comment: This one worked for me ,                                                                                       
       @concat('{
    "sourceTable": "table",
    "query": "select * from tablewhere RegionCode = ', item().RegionCode , '",
    "outputFileType": "csv",
    "optionList":"nullValue=null|delimiter=\t|header=false",
    "outputFolder":"R',item().RegionCode,'file-{YYYY}-{MM}-{dd}-{HH}-{mm}-{ss}.txt"    }'
    )